# Accessing Kth fold per iteration in pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am working on a Pipeline that includes both transformation and classification. However, the transformation function I am using is a custom function that requires knowledge of the train/test split at any given iteration (Xtrain, Xtest).

I would like to use a FunctionTransformer because I believe it’s what I need.

```
def normalize1(data, mean, std):
   df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

   if mean is None and std is None:
       mean = df.mean(axis=0)
       std = df.std(axis=0)
       normalizedDf = (df - mean)/std
       return normalizedDf.values, mean, std

   normalizedDf = (df - mean)/std
   return normalizedDf.values
```

From there, I defined the following pipeline:

```
cv = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, n_repeats=10, random_state=42)
clf = make_pipeline(FunctionTransformer(normalize1), 
                GridSearchCV(SVC(),
                             param_grid=paramGrid,
                             cv=cv,
                             refit=True))
```

This obviously returns me the following error: `normalize1() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'data', 'mean', and 'std'`

I'd like my pipeline to get the train/test split at a given iteration, apply my normalization function and pass on the new X_train and X_test values to the GridSearch. Any way I can do this?

**FYI**: The normalization function can be explained as such:

*(Variable - mean in training) /std in training*

This is why the function computes the mean and std of the training cohort if `mean is None and std is None` and applies the same normalization on the test set with a given mean and std value.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to have "a custom function that requires knowledge of the train/test split at any given iteration", then you need to place your transformer inside `GridSearchCV`. Your current code transforms the training data first before passing it into `GridSearchCV`.

So first you don't need to return `mean` and `std` :

```
def normalize1(data, mean, std):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

    if mean is None and std is None:
        mean = df.mean(axis=0)
        std = df.std(axis=0)
        normalizedDf = (df - mean)/std
        return normalizedDf.values

    normalizedDf = (df - mean)/std
    return normalizedDf.values
```

Then you provide arguments for your function inside `FunctionTransformer` :

```
pipeline = make_pipeline(
FunctionTransformer(normalize1,kw_args={'mean':None,'std':None}), 
SVC())
clf = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid={}, cv=cv, refit=True)
```

We can fit it:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
X,y = make_classification()

clf.fit(X,y)
```

You can try to set the default

```
def normalize1(data, mean = None , std = None):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

    if mean is None and std is None:
        mean = df.mean(axis=0)
        std = df.std(axis=0)
        normalizedDf = (df - mean)/std
        return normalizedDf.values
    
    normalizedDf = (df - mean)/std
    return normalizedDf.values

pipeline = make_pipeline(FunctionTransformer(normalize1),SVC())
clf = GridSearchCV(clf,param_grid={},cv=cv,refit=True)
clf.fit(X,y)
```